# Why doesn't UserDetails' isAccountNonLocked() method work?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

The DB user's status is BLOCKED, but this user can log in to the app. My UserDetails implementation is below:

```
class CustomUserDetails(val userDto: UserAuthResponse) : UserDetails, Serializable {

    override fun isAccountNonLocked() = userDto.status != UserStatus.BLOCKED

    override fun getAuthorities() = listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority(userDto.role.name))
    
    override fun isEnabled() = userDto.status != UserStatus.BLOCKED
    
    override fun getUsername() = userDto.phoneNumber
        
    override fun isCredentialsNonExpired() = userDto.status != UserStatus.BLOCKED
        
    override fun getPassword() = userDto.password
        
    override fun isAccountNonExpired() = userDto.status != UserStatus.BLOCKED
    
}
```

Comment: Please, check your logic, its can be from it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.